# FreeRTOS getting the current time

Tags: date, freertos

I have code that runs with FreeRTOS and I want to edit it,
its a code that measure the pressure and the temperature, and I want to have the time when these measures are token.

Could anyone tell me how to get the current time in my machine or the date?

Thank you.

This is the code that I am using right now.

```
//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "platform.h"
#include "printf.h"
#include "lps331ap.h"

static void app_task(void *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // Initialize the platform
    platform_init();

    // Create a task for the application
    xTaskCreate(app_task, (const signed char * const) "lps331", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 1, NULL);

    // Run
    platform_run();
    return 0;
}

static void app_task(void *param)
{
    uint32_t pres;
    int16_t temp;
    int count=0;

   // FILE* fichier = NULL;

    printf("# Testing LPS331AP\n");

    printf("# Initializing LPS331AP...\n");
    lps331ap_powerdown();

    printf("# Setting LPS331AP pressure sensor\n");
    lps331ap_set_datarate(LPS331AP_P_12_5HZ_T_12_5HZ);

    while (1)
    {
        lps331ap_read_pres(&pres);
        lps331ap_read_temp(&temp);
        //fichier = fopen("test.txt", "w");
        //fprintf(fichier,"%f", pres / 4096.0);
        //fprintf(fichier,"%f", 42.5 + temp / 480.0 );
        printf("%d\t",count);

        printf("%f\t", 42.5 + temp / 480.0);

        printf("%f\n", pres / 4096.0);

        count=count+1;
        //fclose(fichier);

        //vTaskDelay(configTICK_RATE_HZ / 10);
        vTaskDelay(2000);
        //vTaskDelay(600000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For measuring time, there's [xTaskGetTickCount](http://www.freertos.org/a00021.html#xTaskGetTickCount), but this will be limited to the resolution of your tick rate.

Alternatively, you can create another task that ticks at 1 Hz to increment a counter and use that as system time.

To get an actual date however, you'll need to consult your development board and see if it has an RTC. Otherwise, you'll need to get the time manually somehow and maintain this count using your development board's hardware timers.

There's bound to be some hardware clocks in your development board that you can use to measure time as well.